# Can I remove an entity from DbContext if its not valid?

Tags: ef-core-2.2

Im getting errors when I try to remove an entity with Dbcontext.Remove(my_entity).  I am doing a search, which finds the entity in the Db and it along with others are to be removed when I call SaveChanges.

However, since my EF model on this entity says that some fields are required, and even though the entities in the Db have **empty string values** in these fields, I cant seem to remove them when savechanges is called, since I think the model validation is failing.

So in the model for this particular entity, I have data annotations like this

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string RackCode { get; set; }
```

Now, in the Db, there are null values in this field for the list of entities that I am removing.  How can I get EF to let me remove these?

Comment: (1) There is no "model validation" in EF Core. (2) If the database values can be null, then the property should not be marked as `[Required]`.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say empty strings, not actual null values and these particular records are getting in the Db from another application that creates them.  My ad-hoc solution is to set a "dummy" value on the entity before removing it.

Comment: Can you provide the exception message and call stack?